# C++ How to check if variable is std::string type?

Tags: c++, string

I am using template functions, and need a way of testing if a variable is a std::string type to then distinguish it from integer inputs etc, as the operation i need on the string is different from ints. I am having trouble using typeid to do this.

Comment: You usually want to use (partial) specialization or overloading, so in the specialization/overload you simply *know* what type that variable is.

Comment: Can you provide further context? Testing which variable, in what context, to solve what problem?

Comment: This is an assignment, and its a specified to use template functions. For example, I may need to take away two numbers, but also takeaway a segment of a word from another word. E.g if i had the word pizzahut, and the two variables in the template function were entered as pizzahut and hut, I would have to return pizza. Now the problem is in the function i need a way of distinguishing between ints and strings.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Can one partially specialize function templates? Would trying that not just add a new base template as an overload?

Comment: No, there's no partial specialization of function templates. Partial specialization would only apply if you created a templated function object instead of an actual function template.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just overload:

```
template<typename T>
void myFunc(T t) {/* */}

void myFunc(std::string s) {/* */}
```

If different things need to happen for different types, it should probably be in different functions. That way the code isn't cluttered with type checks. You should prefer to let the compiler worry about matching overloads to types.

If you are in a template context, and need to call your function like `myFunc<T>(t)` then you can fully specialize instead:

```
template<>
void myFunc<std::string>(std::string s) {/* */}
```